# Exclude custom post type from list

Tags: custom-post-types

```
 <?php 
    $custom_post_types = get_post_types( 
        array(
            '_builtin' => false,
            'public' => true
        ),
        'objects'
     );

    foreach ( $custom_post_types as $custom_post_type ) {
        $custom_post_type->permalink = get_post_type_archive_link( $custom_post_type->label );
    }

    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $custom_post_types as $custom_post_type ) {
        echo '<li>';
        echo '<a href="' . $custom_post_type->permalink . '">' . $custom_post_type->label . '</a>';
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    ?>
```

I want to exclude products and sales CPT from the list. Can anyone help please? Also I want to display the list in ACS order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
    $custom_post_types = get_post_types( 
        array(
                '_builtin' => false,
                'public' => true
            ),
            'objects'
        );

        ksort( $custom_post_types, SORT_ASC );

        echo '<ul>';

        foreach ( $custom_post_types as $custom_post_type ) {

            $exclude = array( 'products', 'sales' );

            if( TRUE === in_array( $custom_post_type->name, $exclude ) )
                continue;

            $custom_post_type->permalink = get_post_type_archive_link( $custom_post_type->name );

            echo '<li>';
            echo '<a href="' . $custom_post_type->permalink . '">' . $custom_post_type->label . '</a>';
            echo '</li>';

        }

        echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: The ASC and exclude all working fine but the links doesnt work anymore :(

Comment: @mandy At `get_post_type_archive_link()` use  `$custom_post_type->name` instead of `$custom_post_type->label`. This works for me.

Comment: hi thank you sooooo much :) all working fine now :)